# How to duplicate a graph in Google Docs and use a separate source/link of data

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace, google-docs

When I copy and paste a graph in Google Docs, it makes 2 graphs, linked to the same spreadsheet. I'm looking to make 100 identically-styled graphs and quickly modify each one by editing the data in each.

Any idea how to duplicate the source table, so that I can modify each one independently?

Comment: If you create a bunch of charts in the spreadsheet (which can be done with a script), and edit data there, it's possible to insert all of them in a Google Document _as static images_ ([described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44123066)). But to my knowledge, one cannot programmatically create an actual chart in Google Documents.

Comment: @Desire it doesn't need to be programmatic. I just want to copy and paste an existing chart the I inserted into a Google Doc, and use the same style to make another.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem. As long as all of your sheets are formatted the same (column headers and data all in the same place) it should work. Copy the chart and paste it into the new sheet. Click on **Edit Sheet**. Under *Data Range* it should have something like `Sheet1!A1:B5`. Just change the sheet number to match the sheet you pasted the chart into. Sheet 2 should read `Sheet2!A1:B5`, 3 should read `Sheet3!A1:B5`, and on from there.